# Idiomatic way to define new vs persisted types in Haskell

Tags: postgresql, rest, haskell, servant

I have a type that represents a persisted record.  I want to have a very similar type that represents data that should be POSTed to create a new record.

This is the full type:

```
data Record = Reading
  { id: UUID
  , value: String
  ...
  }
```

the "new" type is the same minus the "id", which will be auto-generated by the db.  How can I define this type?  I am using servant to define the API.

My current strategy is to prefix the type and all fields with "new", which works but is reduntant for many-field models.  I have also seen the nested strategy where I have a common shared type.  I've also thought about making the id optional, but I really don't want to be able to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this with a [Higher Kinded Data](https://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data/) like approach.

First, some imports:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module Example where

import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Proxy
import Data.UUID 
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics
```

Then, define a record with a higher kinded type parameter:

```hs
data Record f = Record  { recordId :: f UUID, recordValue :: String } deriving (Generic)
```

The [`Identity` Functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) gives you a variant on this record which *always has* an Id.

```hs
type RecordWithId = Record Identity
```

Using `Maybe` gives you a variant with an *optional* id.

```hs
type RecordWithOptionalId = Record Maybe
```

[`Proxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7/docs/Data-Proxy.html) can be used as a Functor with a single uninteresting "unit" value. (and no values of the wrapped type). This lets us create a type for a `Record` with no ID.

```hs
type RecordWithoutId = Record (Proxy)
```

We can derive `Show` for our `Record`.

```hs
deriving instance (Show (f UUID)) => Show (Record f)
```

Passing `omitNothingFields = True` and `allowOmitedFields = True` in the [`Aeson` instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.2.1.0) is required to parse a `RecordWithoutId` as you'd expect. This does require a version of Aeson >= 2.2.0.0 (which as of writing is more recent than the latest Stackage Snapshot). You could probably implement the Aeson instances by hand if this version bound doesn't work for you.

```hs
instance (ToJSON (f UUID)) => ToJSON (Record f) where
    toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions { omitNothingFields = True, allowOmitedFields = True }

instance (FromJSON (f UUID)) => FromJSON (Record f) where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions { omitNothingFields = True, allowOmitedFields = True }
```

Encoding a value with an ID:

```
ghci> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BL
ghci> BL.putStrLn $ encode (Record {recordId = Identity nil, recordValue = "value" })
{"recordId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","recordValue":"value"}
```

Encoding a value without an ID:

```
ghci> BL.putStrLn $ encode (Record {recordId = Proxy, recordValue = "value" })
{"recordValue":"value"}
```

Decoding a value without an ID

```
ghci> decode "{\"recordValue\":\"value\"}" :: Maybe RecordWithoutId
Just (Record {recordId = Proxy, recordValue = "value"})
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Introduced a lot of new concepts to me and it works!

Comment: The Aeson instances were helpful, but I am not entirely following what those options are doing, particularly `allowOmitedFields`.   It would also be great to not have to use `Identity` when constructing a `Record` with Id.  The article you linked says this is possible but I haven't quite wrangled it.

Comment: without the `allowOmitedFields`, Aeson expects a null value for `recordId` to be present, and will fail to parse if this is missing. so you need `{"recordValue":"value", "recordId":null}` as the JSON representation, which generally isn't what you'd want.

Comment: Gotchya.  Approach is working great.  One thing I noticed is that decoding to a value without an ID does allow an Id to be given - even though it is ignored and the field is really a Proxy.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach I've used a bit is to define my records without an ID, and use a single generic wrapper type that can add an ID to anything.

Something like this (where I used the term "key" rather than "id" mainly to avoid clashing with the built in `id` function, and partially because "Keyed" had a nicer ring to it than "Ided" or "WithId", or whatever):

```
newtype Key a = Key UUID

data Keyed a = Keyed
  { key :: Key a
  , value :: a
  }

data Student = Student
  { name :: Text
  , course :: Course
  , ...
  }
```

My reasoning was that a value of the type `Student` **on its own** is just an immutable value. If you change the name of that record you simply compute a *different* `Student` value, rather than a representation of a concept like "a student has changed their name". We usually fix this by adding an ID value that is supposed to uniquely correspond to the larger more abstract concept of a *real* student, so that we can tell when two student *records* are about the same *real* student (and so that other records can refer to the real student as well).

But associating an identity value like this is an additional (and significant) add-on **on top** of the raw record data, and it's a feature that usually relies on the centralised position of a server or database. But it's also a separate feature that can be applied to any data record. An id/key is not logically a *part* of a student record, it's a feature of our system that allows different student records that exist at different times to be associated with the larger concept of a student in the real world who changes over time. So I find it very useful to have *different* types for a record that has been associated with an external concept by adding an id, and for just the record itself.

Then I would use `Student` in APIs where a client was *only* talking about the details of some student (such as posting data to instruct the server to create a new student record). And I can use `Key Student` where the client is only dealing in identifying a particular student (such as getting the current details of a student for whom the client already knows the ID), and `Keyed Student` when dealing with the record contents in the context of it having been assigned an ID (such as when posting an update).

But this separation isn't just for type-checking the API requiring the id/key field to be present or absent. I actually use both types within my client and server codebases, not just for communication between the two. Client-level code frequently just isn't in a position to do anything sensible with IDs other than receive them from the server and pass them back unaltered, but does need to actually deal in IDs to properly form requests so I can't just hide the ID field from the client entirely. I find it very useful to be able to write parts of my code where they can't possibly mess up ID handling because they're never given a type that contains the ID in the first place. For example, a form for editing student details almost certainly should only deal in `Student`, because it shouldn't allow editing of the id (a nice side effect is this then makes it easy to reuse the same form for creating new students and editing existing ones).

The HKD pattern suggested by Joe works just as well for creating this separation of types. However the `Keyed` type (and `Key` if you like the phantom type parameter to help catch mixups) and associated helpers is something you only have to write once, whereas the HKD pattern is something you apply to every record. I've found the HKD pattern can also sometimes get in the way of writing other instances, because unless you write the instance specifically for one of the intended variants you always have a field typed `f UUID` for an unknown `f`, which is difficult to work with; the *least* bothersome manifestation is probably that a simple `deriving Show` or `deriving Eq` no longer works; you need to use standalone deriving to be more explicit about the constraints on the derived instance. With the approach of a wrapper type adding the id, both the plain record and the `Keyed` wrapper are bog-standard simple data types.

(And note that the article Joe linked is using an example where a single higher-kinded `f` parameter is applied uniformly to *every* field, to easily generate variant types where all of the fields might be missing in order to handle things like form validation. This is quite a different use case to having a single field where you want variants of the data type to have that field present or not. If you like the HKD technique it's really easy to come up with several other different use cases requiring a higher-kinded type parameter to be applied to different fields, and when try supporting multiple of these use-cases at the same time you have to add multiple higher-kinded type parameters that you can vary for different reasons, and everything just becomes a lot more messy. The HKD technique **is** one I quite like, but I've found it best to use in types that are quite "contained", like a type that is *only* used to process a form)

The main drawbacks of the id-wrapper approach are:

1. You do have to write a bit of extra code applying and removing the wrapper at the boundaries between parts of the system that deal with the larger mutable concept and parts that just deal with the simple data itself. A few simple helper functions (or lenses) go a long way, but it's still there.
2. Existing external systems are not usually structured this way, so if you're interfacing with those the mismatch can be a little irksome. (e.g. if you're using an external JSON API, it would take fairly custom instances like `ToJSON a => ToJSON (Keyed a)` to translate, and in the worst case you might not be able to handle it with a single generic instance). It works best when you're in control of both the client and the server and can write the APIs to fit your data types, rather than writing data types to fit existing APIs.
3. Applying and removing wrappers has a performance cost. In many contexts it would be negligible, but it's non-zero.

Comment: This is great, really appreciate the in-depth explanation.  I think this is going to be the standard approach for me.  I control the client and do not mind the wrapping perf at the moment.  I think using HKD in forms also makes sense.

Comment: I am having trouble trying to get a `fromRow` instance to work, I am using postgresql-simple.  Do you know if this is possible to define in a generic way, ideally `instance (FromRow a) => FromRow (Keyed a)`

Comment: @Razumov Hmm, I missed the postgresql tag and instead picked up on the reference to POST, so I was thinking more about the API side than the DB side. An SQL database that insists on records being "flat" *is* one of those existing external systems that are not usually structured this way. That said, and while I haven't actually used `postgresql-simple` much myself, it looks like the `(FromRow a, FromRow b) => FromRow (a :. b)` instance in the library works exactly how one for `FromRow a => FromRow (Keyed a)` would need to, so have a look at that.

Comment: @Razumov I think it might be as simple as `fromRow = Keyed <$> field <*> fromRow`

Comment: @Razumov Oh, but then whatever you're using as the `key` field needs to have a `FromField` instance, of course. Not sure whether `UUID` does out of the box but if you're going with my `Key a` with the phantom parameter, it obviously won't unless you implement or derive it.

Comment: That works.  I did have to define `instance FromField (Key a) where fromField field metadata = Key <$> fromField field metadata` too

Comment: Once the `FromRow` and `FromField` instances are defined, the integration with postgresql-simple "just works" which is pretty cool.  @Ben, even though I control the client, it would be great to a have the ability to present a flattened JSON at the API level, keeping the idea of "keyed as a feature" completely internal to the server.  Maybe possible through a custom `ToJSON` instance?

Comment: @Razumov Yeah, you should be able to make an instance assumes the `value` part encodes to a JSON object, into which you insert a field for the key/id. It's a little untidy (what happens if the value already used that field name, or didn't encode to an object?), but should be reliable enough for types you are fully in control of.

Comment: While I had fun writing up the Higher Kinded Data approach, I'd probably recommend this answer as better general advice